# getting scroll bar on clicking the image in outlook in mail template

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2010

I am creating a mail template with responsive.In OutLook when mail is loading  first time, images are not displaying but mail looks good no scroll bar. On clicking the image, image get loaded and automatically  scroll bar comes. Its not responsive. How to avoid this scroll bar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .max-width{
        width:100%;
    }
    .no-margin{
        margin:0;
    }
    .margin-equal{
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .bold{
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .content-main-p{
        padding:0 0 10px 0;
        margin:0;
    }
    .link{
        outline:none;
        border:0;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#0000EE;
    }
    .wrapper{
        padding:0;
        font-family:'Calibri';
        color:#333;
        overflow:hidden;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border:0;
        font-size:14px;
        max-width:100%;
    }
    .content{
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    .content-main{
        padding:10px 0;
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:20px;
        color:#00201d;
    }
    .expert-content table td a{
        word-break:break-all;
    }
    .expert-content table td{
        vertical-align:top;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        min-height:20px;
    }
    .expert-content .list-test li{
        list-style:none;
        display:table-cell;
        padding:0 2% 0 0;
    }
    .expert-content .list-test li p{
        margin:2px 0;
    }
    .expert-content .list-test li a{
        word-break:break-all;
    }
    .expert-content a,.expert-content span,.expert-content font span{
        display:block !important;
        word-break:break-all !important;
    }
    .content-footer{
        border-top:1px solid #BFBFBF;
        padding:10px 0;
        margin:0;
        font-size:10px;
    }
    .address-panel{
        color:#313131;
        line-height:normal;
    }
    .ExternalClass h1{
        font-weight:bolder !important;
    }
    .ExternalClass *{
        line-height:100% !important;
    }
    .expert-content,.address-panel{
        border-top:1px solid #BFBFBF;
        padding:10px 0;
        width:100%;
    }
    .logo-section a img{
        max-width:100%;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        body{
            font-size:11px !important;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

    }    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .wrapper{
            width:100% !important;
        }

    }    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
        .expert-content td{
            width:100%;
            display:block !important;
        }

    }    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .expert-content td{
            width:100%;
            display:block !important;
        }

    }    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        .bg-btn{
            font-size:12px;
            margin-right:-130px;
        }

    }</style></head>

      <body>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper margin-equal" style="width: 100%;max-width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;">
     <!--Email Content table-->
         <tr>
         <td class="max-width">
        <div style="padding: 0 1%;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="position: relative">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content margin-equal" style="width: 100%;max-width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;">
                                <!--Image section-->
                                <tr class="logo-section">
                                    <td style="background-color:#D9D9D9;">
                                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content margin-equal" style="width: 100%;max-width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;position: relative;">
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <img style="max-width: 100%; display: block;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/15e0eb6ff3b427d17752e909f/images/04778e34-84a5-487d-be77-813f1a8a9550.png">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;">
                                                <td>

                                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content margin-equal" style="max-width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div style="border-radius: 3px;background-color: #E18600;background: #E18600; width: 400px;position:relative; top:-100px !important;">

                                                                    <a style="font-size: 16px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;border-radius: 3px;padding: 15px 25px;border: 1px solid #E18600;display: inline-block;" href="http://www.drupalgeeks.com/still-on-drupal-6-and-looking-for-reliable-long-term-support?utm_source=Email%20Marketing&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=Amx-D6-Retainer-MS">        
    Click here                                                                       
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--End Image section-->
                                <!--Main content-->
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="content-main" style="background-color:#D9D9D9;">
                                        <p>Hi ,</p>

                                          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum..</p>
                              <p>xxxx is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker includingversions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

                                        <p>Thanks,<br>
                                            XXXXXXX</p>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <!--End 3 Column Layout -->

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="padding: 10px 0; border-top:1px solid #BFBFBF;"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="logo-section">
                                    <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#595959;line-height: 20px;padding: 20px 0 20px 0;color: #ffffff;">


                                        <div style="padding: 8px 8px 2px 8px;">
                                            <a href="">
                                                <img src="https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/e512ea00cef06b6458a70eca017036ea64ac16d638a7f3b6f64ecc89516cb677a3c5c02d96aa046464ba1eeb74119b940aeef1ad6b4d7159156ec0f5bbc738e2.png">
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="">
                                                <img src="https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/41518b8775122f06178d677e57942f8e8008b80d3891bd2ac70e26ef59ca04173bb473e3ac1866f89e0ea79a395495b29d6cebef12687cfbc302a6913b5a80ab.png">
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="">
                                                <img src="https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cb4ebae50ac0840135990248236b9828610f1828d7f4f49e2f9b4b5683940d3ab2d7a616b3f9228e91525162a4c234157d4100b3e83d00c1fbfdd047b44b7e07.png">
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="">
                                                <img src="https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/037a112de555a804cbe0be286210f3cbc4a9eaa250556e8cd419acdf80395321955758fe23d0fe50b36bdeccf0918b55ef128d8fd59e8812e8dad71b167032ee.png"></a>

                                        </div>


                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#D9D9D9;padding: 10px 0;">
                                            <a style="color:#000000;font-size: 18px;" href="">Visit us</a>|<a style="color:#000000;font-size: 18px;" href="">Unsubscribe</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--End Signature panel-->
                                <!-- Disclaimer -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="content-footer no-margin">
                                        <p class="no-margin" style="padding:0;"><span class="bold">Note: </span>
                                            This is a promotional email which complies with all the guidelines
                                            of CAN-SPAM act 2003. We have found your email address through our own
                                            efforts on the web search and not through any illegal way. If you find
                                            this email unsolicited, please reply with "REMOVE" in the subject line and
                                            we will take care that you don't receive any further promotional mail.
                                        </p>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!--End Disclaimer -->
                            </table>

                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--Footer mountain -->
           </td>
     </tr>
        <!--End Email Content table-->
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're setting the `max-width:` to 100% on every element - why not just set the container to a set width, and then the image to 100% of the container? E.g. `<td style="width:50vw;"><img style="max-width:100%"></td>` **Edit:** It's probably a height issue, too. If you don't want the image to go over a certain height - set the containers height to a fixed amount with the overflow set to hidden.

Comment: Thank you @Gavin ...But its not working in outlook